# MySQL Float(7,2) to PHP Float

Tags: php, pdo, floating-point

I am fetching (with PHP PDO) from MySQL a value (stored in signed Float(7,2) format).

```
Result
=====================
Database = 8.9 //correct value
PHP = 8.8999996185303 //fetch from PHP PDO
```

Sample code:

```
$qry = 'SELECT hours FROM sample WHERE filter=?;';
$stmt = $db->prepare($qry);
$stmt->execute(array($filter));
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['hours'];
}
```

What is the best possible way to fetch this data from the DB?
Ive read about the floating point approximalization issue in PHP.
Thus I was thinking to perhaps change the SQL into something like:

```
SELECT (hours * 100) as butSoExpensiveOnDatabase etc...
```

Or using `round` or `number_format` in PHP.
What would you guys suggest and why?

**Changing the table structure is NOT an option!**

(reason: old legacy code I need to support + no time + no budget)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
"SELECT round(hours, 2) FROM sample WHERE filter=?;"
```

Comment: this works, but isnt there a PHP solution, I dont like to let the mysql server make lots of calculations

Comment: @Terence Using mathematical functions in MySQL is better than having PHP do so.